# Java bytecode SWAP for double and long values?

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm

I am developing a Java instrumentation engine with ASM and there is a situation where the evaluation stack has a certain *value* on the top and I want to insert a *ref* (which is the result of a *getstatic*) before the existing *value*. I.e. considering the stack with just one *value*: `value ->`, then after the *getstatic* I want the stack become like this: `ref, value ->`.

To perform this behavior I must insert the following bytecodes: *getsatic* and *swap*. With ASM I will do something like (consider `mv` of the type `MethodVisitor`):

```
mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, ...);
mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.SWAP);
```

The problem is that the *swap* bytecode does not support `long` and `double` values. So the code above is fine for single word types, but it does not work correctly for `long` and `double` types.

Is there any simple solution to resolve this problem for `long` and `double` types and without requiring an auxiliary local value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have an utility function for ASM that injects the bytecodes for swapping the operands of any type on the top of the stack:

```
public static void swap(MethodVisitor mv, Type stackTop, Type belowTop) {
    if (stackTop.getNumberSlots() == 1) {
        if (belowTop.getNumberSlots() == 1) {
            // Top = 1, below = 1
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.SWAP);
        } else {
            // Top = 1, below = 2
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP_X2);
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.POP);
        }
    } else {
        if (belowTop.getNumberSlots() == 1) {
            // Top = 2, below = 1
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP2_X1);
        } else {
            // Top = 2, below = 2
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP2_X2);
        }
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.POP2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

We have a double word value VV and ref value R. To get from VV... to VVR... you can add your R value to the top of the stack (RVV...) and then use dup_x2 (RVVR...) and then pop (VVR...).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use local variables to swap items on the stack.
Something like:

```
DSTORE tmp
GETSTATIC ...
DLOAD tmp
```

Comment: I would like a simple solution that does not require an auxiliary local value.

Comment: @FernandoMiguelCarvalho I am afraid, it's impossible. Take a look at the byte code commands: we have commands for loading to/from stack. We have commands for different dups, and swap which isn't applicable here.

Comment: Indeed.  The JIT will probably optimize it away anyway if it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sequence dup2x2, pop2.

Starting with XXYY on the stack, dup2x2 gives you YYXXYY, and pop2 leaves you with YYXX.

Comment: That won't work. long/double is a double word value and ref is a single word value.

Comment: Sorry I misread the problem. In that case your refinement of my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Call [org.objectweb.asm.commons.GeneratorAdapter.swap(Type,Type)](http://asm.ow2.org/asm30/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/GeneratorAdapter.html#swap%28org.objectweb.asm.Type,%20org.objectweb.asm.Type%29). It's implemented like this:

```
public void swap(final Type prev, final Type type) {
    if (type.getSize() == 1) {
        if (prev.getSize() == 1) {
            swap(); // same as dupX1(), pop();
        } else {
            dupX2();
            pop();
        }
    } else {
        if (prev.getSize() == 1) {
            dup2X1();
            pop2();
        } else {
            dup2X2();
            pop2();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem today. I feel like local variables could be bypassed in the way of using various DUP and POP command so that ref can be placed appropriately onto the operand stack:

1. value ->

GetStatic

2. value -> ref ->

Dup_X2

3. ref -> value -> ref ->

pop

4. ref -> value ->

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I would ensure the stack is loaded in the order it needs without requiring a swap.
In term of optimising the code, I would suggest you try to produce code as close to what the `javac` generates as possible as this is what the JVM has been tuned to optimise.

If this is not possible, you can store the value in a local variable, push the `ref` and reload the value.

Comment: Yes that’s an option, but I would like a simple solution that does not require an auxiliary local value.

Comment: Add the elements to the stack in a order so that they don't need to be swapped, i.e. swap the order in your code instead.

Comment: It is not possible. I am intercepting the putfield bytecode and at that moment I know that the top of the stack has one value. But it is not easy to determine which previous instruction left the value on the stack for the putfield. That value could be the result of an expression, of a method invocation, or something else. So I cannot change the order of the instructions because I do not know which instructions to change.

Comment: Really this should not be a generic answer and you have to provide specifics.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov I don't understand what you mean. This is how the javac does it and I don't know what specifics you think should be provided.

Comment: Peter, unlike instrumentation of existing bytecode, javac has a view and control of the entire world, i.e. working on a much higher level. This is not applicable here, unless instrumentation engine will recreate the whole state, but that is generally unnecessary and expensive to do.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov ASM supports a tree view of code so you can do this sort of instrumentation, but you are right that its hard to do with the class used in the example.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the tree view of code supported by ASM is very different from AST the javac is dealing with. The only similarity there is that they both are some kind of trees. Yet all of this is unrelated to the original question.

Comment: The original question is how to swap the order of values on the stack and the solution I suggested is to swap the order they are added using ASM. The OP believes this is impractical, but I fail to see how its unrelated.